# What is Roles in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-security

What is Roles in context of Spring Security. How to define it. I am not asking about coding. What is the general definition for roles in spring boot. Someone please give a definition with appropriate example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Roles which we can provide in Spring Security.

If so then your question should be **Roles in Spring Security.**

Roles are basically level of Access you give to a User.

- There might be case where only few Users are allowed to Write data and Others can just read information.
- There might be case where some resources should be accessed by only special set of Users.

In all above case Role plays important part.

Lets see this piece of Code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationMgr) throws Exception {
        authenticationMgr.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("jduser").password("jdu@123").authorities("ROLE_USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("jdadmin").password("jda@123").authorities("ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/homePage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/userPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/adminPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homePage")
                .failureUrl("/loginPage?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")                
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loginPage?logout"); 

    }
}
```

You have configures your application in a way that

`/adminPage`  should only be used by a User having `ROLE_ADMIN`

`/userPage, /homePage` is accessible to both `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER`.

You can define your Custom User Roles. You need to link each User with a Role and configure same in authorizeRequests.

You can find many blogs on this. [Here is one](https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration)